# C as K and S and silent (rules of thumb for pronunciation of C?)

Tags: pronunciación, alfabeto

I am just learning Spanish. For the most part, I find that pronunciation is very consistent. However, I am having a little difficulty with the letter "C." Most of the time it is pronounced like "K" in English, but there are exceptions. In the word "Discipulos" it appears to be silent; in "Cierto" it is pronounced like "S" in English. Are there rules for determining when C is silent, and when it is pronounced like "S" or do I just need to memorize these exceptions?

Comment: In "Discípulos", it is not the "c", which is silent.  "dis" is the first syllable. "cí" is the second syllable. So, the second syllable, "cí" takes the sound, not the first syllable "dis".

Answer (score 17, accepted):

C is never silent.

'c' has three sounds.

1. When combined with 'h' it creates the digraph 'ch' with the same sound as english 'chair' ('choza').
2. When followed by 'a', 'o' or 'u' or by another consonant it has the 'k' sound ('casa', 'cobre', 'ósculo', 'actor').
3. When followed by 'e' or 'i' it has the 'z' sound ('cereza', 'ciruela').

Your problem arises with this third sound. Spanish is divided in two big areas that we can call "standard" and "seseante" (Spanish word for 's-using'). In "seseante" zones (you are learning in one of them, and they are majority through Latin America) the 'z' sound has disappeared and both 'z' and 'ce'-'ci' are pronounced as 's'. So with "discípulos": on a "seseante" zone you have an 's' followed by an 's' sound, and since there is no long 's' in Spanish you end up pronouncing just one 's'.

In summary:

```
Zone         Discípulos      Cereza     Casa    Choza    Acción
Standard     Dis-ZI-pu-los   ze-RE-za   CA-sa   CHO-za   ak-ZION
Seseante     Di-SI-pu-los    se-RE-sa   CA-sa   CHO-sa   ak-SION
```

Comment: The second case (k sound) is also used when c is followed by another consonant, as in *actor*, *octubre*, *acción* (aK-Zión).

Comment: Perhaps you want to add that the sound that you call 'z' sounds like english 'th' in 'thing'

Comment: Considerando que México por si solo tiene más del doble de la población de España, no sé si sea lo más razonable distinguir entre seseante y "estándar". Yo diría que actualmente lo estándar es el seseo, y lo anormal es distinguir s de c.

Answer (score 2):

For `c + vowel` you can memorize the standard rules:

```
1.   ca, co, cu = ka, ko, ku

2.   ce, ci = ze, zi
```

where z is pronounced like 'th' in 'think'

Now, depending on the zone you are, 'seseo' changes all cases of rule 2. into

```
2.   ce, ci = se, si
```

Comment: This is for Spain, right (the "th" sound)? Not Mexico?

Comment: In Mexico is like case 2. We don't pronounce the "th" sound as in Spain. Is a plain "s" sound even por words written with z

zapato = sapato

Answer (score 2):

I would add something to @Envite answer (I can't comment):

In spanish the sound it's more important than the way of writing (always respecting the orthografy). This means that if a word changes you have to update the way you write it.

Also, the 'z' before 'i' and 'e' it's *almost* forbbiden, it turns into 'c', except for very few words for ethimological reasons ("enzima", "zinc","azimut","nazi","zigzag") and in "zeta" (because is it's own name).

This is important in making plurals:

- "procaz" --> "procaces"
- "audaz" --> "audaces"
- "pez" --> "peces"
- "maíz" --> "maíces"
- "vez" --> "veces"
- "nuez" --> "nueces"
- "arroz" --> "arroces"
- "luz" --> "luces"
- "tenaz" --> "tenaces"
- "matiz" --> "matices"
- And a lot more.

And with the "conjugación" of the verbs:

- "cazar" -> "cace" (1ª s.), "cacemos" (1ª p.)…
- "cocer" -> "cuezo" (1ª s.), "cueza" (another tense), …
- "zurcir" -> "zurzo"…
- "sacar" -> "saque" (1ª s.) and "saquemos" (1ª p.).

Answer (score 1):

You are right in American Spanish the sequences *-sci-* and *-sce-* are pronunced always /si/ and /se/ (in European Spanish the most frequent pronunciations are /-sθi-/ and /-sθe-/).

One might expect that the equalization in American Spanish of /s/ and /θ/ would lead to forms such as */-s:e-/ or */-s:i-/, but this is not the case, since Spanish language lacks tense or geminate consonants as Italian does. In American Spanish /-sce-/ and /-sci-/ are pronounced always with a plain consonant:

*ascensor* [asen'soɾ] // *consciente* [kon'sjente]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, C is never silent in Spanish. In Discipulos, both S and C make the [s] sound, kind of like in English where C and K both form the "ck" digraph and both are pronounced [k]. In Spanish, C before I and E produces the [s] sound but also the [th] sound in European Spanish so C certainly isn't silent in those regions.

Comment: Do you mean that English speakers pronounce ck with two k sounds?  We do, for instance pronounce bookcase with two but that is different.